# Export .txt from Sql issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to export a .txt file from a sql script. I don't want any headings. I also don't want any commas (,) dividing my fields and I want them to keep the " which surrounds each value in my table. My code runs but includes headings, removes " from each field and inserts a ,.
My code

```
set echo off
set verify off
set termout on
set heading off
set pages 50000
set feedback off
set newpage none
set linesize 1000
set serveroutput off



spool New_Members.txt

SELECT   'Unique_ID, Name, Alt_Name, Entity_Type, Party_Type,   Reference_#, Addr1, Addr2, Addr3, Town, County, Postcode, 
      Country,ALT_ADDRESS1,ALT_ADDRESS2,ALT_ADDRESS3,ALT_TOWN,ALT_COUNTY,ALT_POST_CODE,ALT_COUNTRY,NATIONALITY,
      DOB,INDIVIDUAL_ID,INDIVIDUAL_ID_TYPE,COUNTRY_OF_REGISTRATION,COMPANY_ID,COMPANY_ID_TYPE,SOURCE_COUNTRY,SOURCE_SYSTEM,TRANSACTION_TYPE' 
from     dual;
/

select   Unique_ID||','||Name||','||Alt_Name||','|| Entity_Type||','||Party_Type||','||Reference_#||','||Addr1||','||Addr2||','||
     Addr3||','||Town||','||County||','||Postcode||','||Country||','||ALT_ADDRESS1||','||ALT_ADDRESS2||','||
     ALT_ADDRESS3||','||ALT_TOWN||','||ALT_COUNTY||','||ALT_POST_CODE||','||ALT_COUNTRY||','||NATIONALITY||','||
     DOB||','||INDIVIDUAL_ID||','||INDIVIDUAL_ID_TYPE||','||COUNTRY_OF_REGISTRATION||','||COMPANY_ID||','||COMPANY_ID_TYPE||','||
     SOURCE_COUNTRY||','||SOURCE_SYSTEM||','||TRANSACTION_TYPE
from     dbo.Temp_Weekly_Export_File;
/


spool off;

exit
```

Comment: do you get an error when you run the script? if so, include the error message

Comment: My code runs, but removes headings and double quotes. It also inserts commas.

Comment: You code does not show any double quotes which could be removed, It inserts comma as you write `||','||`

Comment: It's doing exactly what you told it to do

Comment: Apologies, one of those days. How do I turn off the headings?

Comment: Headings are already off `set heading off`

Comment: You've already got `set heading off`, but you can change to `set pagesize 0` instead.

Comment: You are generating your custom 'header' row twice though - you terminate and execute with `;` and then re-execute the current buffer with the `/`, so remove one of those. You probably don't really want line breaks in that string literal, either - move it to one line, or concatenate shorter lines together instead. You might also want to set `trimout` and `trimspool` on.

Comment: I have added set pagesize 0 and still have set heading off but am still getting column headings in my results?

Comment: You'll get the header you are explicitly generating, but not the original column headings (you aren't selecting the columns individually, for a start). You can tell it's yours if the header has `Unique_ID` in mixed case; if it was a normal header it would all be uppercase. (You're also running your real query twice, as that also has both `;` and `/`, but that's a side issue).

Comment: How do I just generate the results? I have adapted code and this seems to be the template. Can I simply select the results and not the heading?

Comment: @E_McAndrew - yes, of course - if you don't want the generated heading, just remove the first query that produces it. And remember to remove the final `/` after the second query, so it isn't executed twice - as I said above, you need `;` or `/` but not both.

Comment: Thanks Alex. If you want to submit it as the answer then I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have `set header off`, so you won't see any Oracle-generated column headings. Setting `pagesize` to zero would also suppress the headers. You may find it helpful to also `set trimout on` and `set trimspool on`.

What you seem to be seeing is the CSV header that you are explicitly generating with your first query. If you don't want to see that header line, just remove it from your script.

If you keep that header, remove the extra whitespace and particularly the line breaks, as they will cause the header to be treated as multiple rows when import to Excel etc. If you were trying to stop that line being too long in your script, you could concatenate multiple shorter strings instead:

```
select 'Unique_ID,Name,Alt_Name,Entity_Type,Party_Type,Reference_#,'
  || 'Addr1,Addr2,Addr3,Town,County,Postcode,Country,ALT_ADDRESS1,'
  || 'ALT_ADDRESS2,ALT_ADDRESS3,ALT_TOWN,ALT_COUNTY,ALT_POST_CODE,'
  || 'ALT_COUNTRY,NATIONALITY,DOB,INDIVIDUAL_ID,INDIVIDUAL_ID_TYPE,'
  || 'COUNTRY_OF_REGISTRATION,COMPANY_ID,COMPANY_ID_TYPE,'
  || 'SOURCE_COUNTRY,SOURCE_SYSTEM,TRANSACTION_TYPE' 
from dual;
```

You are running both of your queries twice, because each of them is terminated with a semicolon (`;`) which [submits that statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_four.htm#sthref273); and is then followed by [a slash (`/`)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve004.htm#SQPUG162), which re-executes the current command buffer. You only need one or the other, so I'd remove both the slashes - but whichever you remove, be consistent, and check if there are coding guidelines in your organisation which prefer one over the other.

As noted in comments, your question is a bit confused, as you're explicitly adding commas and there are no double-quotes to remove. You may actually want to add double-quotes though, if any of the column values can contain the comma delimiter - which would confuse Excel (or whatever will use this file). You can concatenate double-quotes around specific fields as required, e.g.:

```
select Unique_ID||','||Name||','||Alt_Name||','|| Entity_Type||','||
  Party_Type||','||Reference_#||',"'||Addr1||'","'||Addr2||'",'||
...
```

which would enclose the first two address column values in double-quotes in the output.